# when the TLS handshake is finished when i send the ldap_sasl_bind request to do the simple bind server is ignoring/rejecting the request?

Tags: ssl, ldap, tls1.2, openldap

by using ldap_get_option im getting the socket_fd and then doing the ssl_connect() to do the handshake in the tls 1.2 version..

```
                int socket_fd = -1;
                
                int err = ldap_get_option(m_connection, LDAP_OPT_DESC, &socket_fd);
                
                if (errcode != LDAP_SUCCESS) 
                {
                    std::cout<<"the ldap get failed"<<std::endl;
                }

                std::cout<<"the socket_fd"<<socket_fd<<std::endl;

                // Initialize OpenSSL and create SSL context
                SSL_library_init();
                SSL_load_error_strings();
                OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
                SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_client_method());

                SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
                SSL_set_fd(ssl, socket_fd);

                // Set up OpenSSL message callback
                SSL_set_msg_callback_arg(ssl, this); // Set the context for the callback
                SSL_set_msg_callback(ssl, TlsProtocolMsgCallback);
                
                // Perform TLS handshake
                if (SSL_connect(ssl) != 1) {
                }
                else {
                 // sending the bind
                }
```

in the else of the above im sending the `ldap_sasl_bind (simple)`:

```
int err = ldap_sasl_bind(m_connection,dn.c_str(),NULL, tcred, NULL, NULL , &msgID);
```

so in the pcap
im getting ignored unknown record ..!

im expecting that the ldap bind to be send without being ignored and receive the response

Comment: int err = ldap_sasl_bind(m_connection,dn.c_str(),NULL, tcred, NULL, NULL , &msgID);

this above method do simple binding

@SteffenUllrich i want to send the bind request after the TLS handshake , which is not happening , because im getting "ignore unknown record" from the server in the pcap...!! the ssl_connect is != 1 condition failed, that means its success right , then im sending the bind request ?